# Sorting redis big data by value

Tags: redis

For example, I'm setting the data like following to redis.

```
SET "projects:views:PROJECT_NAME1" 17
SET "projects:views:PROJECT_NAME2" 13
SET "projects:views:PROJECT_NAME3" 21
```

`PROJECT_NAME` differs according to project record name that I get from relational database.

How can I sort all "project:views:*" by value. In this example our output should be

```
PROJECT_NAME3 21
PROJECT_NAME1 17
PROJECT_NAME2 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them to a sorted set like this:

```
ZADD "projects:views" 17 PROJECT_NAME1 13 PROJECT_NAME2 21 PROJECT_NAME3
```

Then call:

```
ZREVRANGE projects:views 0 -1 WITHSCORES
```

Check [here](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) what other things a sorted set can do

Comment: Caveat: if the score can be the same as another you may need to do a secondary client-side sort (or use Lua) to determine and order on the secondary criteria. There is `ZRANGEBYLEX` but it is for cases where all scores are the same. Also, if you have a lot of members to add you are not likely to enjoy the performance effects of a large ZADD call.